# IDA Pro - rewriting HIBYTE, LOBYTE and __OFSUB__ macros to C++

Tags: c++, macros, reverse-engineering, ida

I was able to hook one function and now I'm trying to rewrite it's code, but I have issues with
translating some macros generated by IDA Pro's pseudocode

```
 LOBYTE(v8) = v8 & 3;  
 LOBYTE(v12) = 0;
 HIBYTE(v12) = *result;
 v21 = __OFSUB__(v24 + 1, 30);
```

LOBYTE and HIBYTE are detected by Visual Studio but when I copy-paste them I get this error

> Error (active)    E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue

I tried to rewrite it to something like this

> LOBYTE(v8); v8 = v8 & 3;

and then the error dissappears, but it doesn't seem to work fine.
As for offsub, it is not detected at all as a valid macro.

Do you have any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOBYTE` and `HIBYTE` are macros that do some bit shifting logic so you can extract specific values from an `unsigned short`. So, for example if you had an `unsigned short` with value `0xAB93`, you could get the specific bytes as so:

```
unsigned char lo = LOBYTE(0xAB93);
unsigned char hi = HIBYTE(0xAB93);
```

`lo` would hold the value `0x93` and `hi` would hold the value `0xAB`

You want to use a separate macro to combine the values. For example:

```
unsigned short both = MAKEWORD(lo,hi);
```

Comment: Note: HIBYTE **used** to mean that, but it has changed (contrary to IDA 7.0 defs.h and minwindef.h) to mean *the highest byte*, e.g., BYTE7 in an __int64.  Not sure when this happened, but somewhere between 7.1 and 7.5.  Not cool IDA.

After C++ conversion, it now looks like this: ```*(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(&x)+(sizeof x/sizeof(uint8) - 1))```

Answer (score 1):

You can find this macros definations in the `IDA_INSTALL_PATH/plugins/defs.h` file.
You can find all things about the IDA use Macros.